# How to load loader in blank areas of Flatlist when a item takes long to render and produces a blank space?

Tags: performance, react-native, listview, react-native-flatlist, recyclerlistview

I want to load loader in the blank spaces of white space. Because during fast scroll Flatlist leaves blank spaces which seems weird. And those blank spaces takes time to go away to render original item.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can prevent displaying of the blank space.
FlatList itself has some props for that you can find here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

For example ListEmptyComponent can be used like this:

```
<FlatList
     ListEmptyComponent={() => <ActivityIndicator color={"blue"}/>}
/>
```

You can also play with `initialNumToRender`  to see what is the optimum value for you. Its default value is 10.
Check this article for more suggestions: https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b